# Invoking applet method via JavaScript won't work

Tags: java, javascript, applet, internet-explorer-9

I am invoking methods of a Java applet via JavaScript, using the following:

```
document.myApplet.myMethod();
```

However, this only works perfectly when I add the site to trusted site and set the security to low. Otherwise, it throws me this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'myMethod'

How can I solve this?

Chrome prompts me if I want to execute the applet.

Full code snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getKey() {
    var key = document.myApplet.mymethod();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getKey()">
<applet id="myApplet" archive="myApplet.jar" code="myApplet.class" width="0" height="0"></applet> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code for embedding the applet, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an **Object** tag instead of applet tag like this

```
 <object type="application/x-java-applet" width="0" height="0" name="appId">
        <param name="code" value="myApplet" />
        <param name="archive" value="myApplet.jar" />   
 </object>
```

And your Javascript like this:

```
function getKey() {
   var key = appId.mymethod();
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks to that and the following: I changed the <applet> tag to <object>; I changed the method invokation by first assigning the Applet to an object var clientObject = myApplet and then calling the method var result = myApplet.myMethod(); and granting ActiveX priviledges to my browser.